# Cohen to date a baalas Tshuvah

Tags: halacha

I’m a Cohen and I wanted to know if it’s required of me to ask a girl which I know that she had sexual relationships in the past if she had a relationship with a nine Jew and is the fact that most probably if she had it was with a condom makes a difference. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. This site doesn't specialize in answering personal questions such as yours. If you generalize it, you'll avoid it getting closed. Such as: are Kohanim required to inquire about the prior intimate relationships of prospective wives.

Comment: Very closely related (partial duplicate): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37686

Comment: I would call this a duplicate of that. As far as the second part of the question (the condom), it wouldn't help, because there still is haarah (inserting the member), which is enough to make the women a zonah in a case when the intercourse does.