# Relationships and Intimacy

Tags: marriage, sexuality

A girl (21) recently confessed her love for me, and she’s a nice girl, but she’s not a virgin.  I approach all possible romantic relationships very seriously with the intent of marriage, and I don’t know whether I should proceed here.  She’s started becoming more religious, but I don’t know if it’s for me or for G-d.  What are the Halachik ramifications for her? what does the tradition say regarding these kinds of matters? What do secular studies say about these kinds of marriages? There’s a certain amount of disgust in knowing that another man (that she wasn’t married to) has been in her, is that warranted/reasonable? Is that a reason to reject her?  I need advice and wisdom regarding this, thank you whoever takes the time to answer this.

Comment: See the sidebar: "Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but *does not offer personalized, professional advice,* and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)."

Comment: If you're turning to the interwebs for advice — this is not the place. There are various other online ask-a-rabbi's that offer advice. One such option is instaRabbi. Best of luck

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34341/21

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya "Ben" and thanks for this first question. Your question is likely to be closed closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this couple needs to talk to a competent rabbi, and probably a relationship therapist.

Let's call this three issues:

A.) There's a mismatch between the religious upbringing of the pair.

Just something they need to be aware of, and plan through. If one says *but that's how my very-kosher family always did it*, what will the other say? Is one of them currently at a different level of observance? How do they intend to navigate such issues?

B.) It's possible one side is taking on more religious practice solely out of interest in the partner.

I mean there's no law about this, but if it's not sincere, that's just not a recipe for a good relationship. These conversations come up a lot with conversions; one rabbi heard a woman say "I came to Judaism *through* my boyfriend, not *because* of my boyfriend"; he felt that was reasonable. A conversion beit din would typically ask -- *suppose the Jewish partner suddenly wasn't in the picture; would you continue your interest in Judaism?*

C.) One side's been "a good teenager", while the other hasn't.

Really it's about what the couple works out for themselves. There's no "thou shalt / thou shalt not" about this. (Unless he's a kohen and she had a non-Jewish boyfriend...). If one side really can't get over this, then it's not a good match because they can't get over it. If they can, that's fine too. There are plenty of solidly happy, religious couples where one had less-religious past, and all that it entails. Okay at some point if everything proceeds, there will be questions about exactly what wording to put in the *ketubah*, and then what exactly should be pronounced out-loud ... but those are details that can be worked out.